# Rename only the last column in pandas dataframe (accounting for duplicate headers)

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need to rename **only** the last column in my dataframe, the issue is **there are many columns with the same name** (there is a reason for this), thus I cannot use the code in other examples online. Is there a way to use something specific that just isolates the final column?

I have tried to do something like this
`df.rename(columns={df.columns[-1]: 'Test'}, inplace=True)`

However this then means that all columns with that same header are changed to 'Test', whereas I just want the last one to change.

I kind of need something like `df.columns[-1] = 'Test'`  but this doesn't work.

Comment: Please provide a concrete example.

Answer (score 45, accepted):

You can always explicitly reassign.

```
df.columns = [*df.columns[:-1], 'Test']
```

Or, if you want to method chain, use `set_axis` the same way:

```
df.set_axis([*df.columns[:-1], 'Test'], axis=1, inplace=False)
```

---

**Minimal Code Example**

```
df = pd.DataFrame([[1, 2, 3], [4, 5, 6], [7, 8, 9]], columns=list('ABA'))
df

   A  B  A
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

df.rename({df.columns[-1]: 'C'}, axis=1) # wrong

   C  B  C
0  1  2  3
1  4  5  6
2  7  8  9

df.set_axis([*df.columns[:-1], 'Test'], axis=1, inplace=False)

   A  B  Test
0  1  2     3
1  4  5     6
2  7  8     9
```